# Need to Convert Array Output to String Outside of a For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random, encapsulation

I'm trying to practice with arrays in prep for my Java SE 11 test and I need help getting my random name generator to work. Right now, I'm not concerned about the name being "valid" (a truly random name like Xvtwg is fine).

I have built a loop where a random value between 3 and 10 is generated (length of name) and then a random index between 0 and 25 is chosen for each loop pass to grab a random letter of the alphabet. All of this works, and I am able to take the output array from the loop and turn it into a concatenated string in the loop. The problem occurs later when I need to call the local variable nameFinal as a value for the set function.

I have tried to declare the output string both inside and outside the loop but both ways I return "nameFinal cannot be resolved to a variable." I have also tried moving my output array outside of the loop (and redefining its output), but return the same variable."

I added in a try/catch block to try to illustrate this issue better. Here is my code:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Build random values
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        //Name random index 3-10 char
        int nmax = 10;
        int nmin = 3;
        int rand1 = (int)(Math.random() * (nmax - nmin + 1) + nmin);
        //Create random name from total number of letters
        //Define Array of letters
        String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        //Create random index to pull a random letter over the length of the random index
        int lmax = 25;
        int lmin = 0;
        //I have also tried declaring newName and nameFinal here
        for(int i = 0; i <= rand1; i++) {
            int randl = (int)(Math.random() * (lmax - lmin + 1) + lmin);
            String[] newName;
            newName[i] = letters[i];
            String nameFinal = Arrays.toString(newName);
        }
        //Concatenate array of random letters into a "name"
        try{
            String nameFinal = Arrays.toString(newName);
            System.out.println(nameFinal);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace()
        }
        //Implementation omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: take the declaration String nameFinal="" before the loop, but set its value inside the loop. Forget about new name, and just concatenate one letter at a time onto the String.

Comment: Can whoever posted the down vote please let me know why? I spent a bunch of time researching the question before posting, and carefully checked how was I asking it and made sure it was as thorough and detailed as could be needed...

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Pause work on the overall goal. Chop code to the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Find the 1st point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what it is supposed to be. (Debugging fundamentals.) Say what you expect & why with justification per authoritative documentation. [ask]

Comment: Fair enough, appreciate the tips. That said, is it really necessary to go back and downvote my question from months ago over that? I'll do my best to edit it, though this question is solved with an answer already :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit. Hope this will help you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Build random values
    Random rand = new Random();
    Test test = new Test();
    test.randomName();
    test.createAge();
    test.createSSN();
}

//Name random index 3-10 char
public void randomName() {
    int nmax = 10;
    int nmin = 3;
    int rand1 = (int)(Math.random() * (nmax - nmin + 1) + nmin);
    //Create random name from total number of letters
    //Define Array of letters
    String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

    //Create random index to pull a random letter over the length of the random index
    int lmax = 25;
    int lmin = 0;

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>(5);
    for(int i = 0; i <= rand1; i++) {
        int randl = (int)(Math.random() * (lmax - lmin + 1) + lmin);
        name.add(letters[rand1]);
    }
    System.out.println(name.toString());
}

//Age random number between 1 and 100
private void createAge(){
    int amax = 100;
    int amin = 1;
    int rand2 = (int)(Math.random() * (amax - amin + 1) + amin);
}

//SSN random 9 digit number
private void createSSN(){
    int smax = 999999999;
    int smin = 100000000;
    int rand3 = (int)(Math.random() * (smax - smin + 1) + smin);
}
   
}
```

Comment: Made this encapsulated with classes. The big, blocky text I had put into this was hard to read and this really helps create improved reference material